# ¿Cómo pasar argumentos a una función que es párametro de otra? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estaba leyendo el capítulo 5 *High order functions*, del libro *Eloquent JavaScript* en el cual se detalla el siguiente código:

```
function repeat(n, action) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    action(i);
  }
}

repeat(3, console.log);
// → 0
// → 1
// → 2
```

Entiendo la idea de repetir una acción, pero veo que la función *action()* toma como argumento el valor de la variable *i* que está definida dentro de la otra función. Existe una forma de pasarle parámetros a *console.log* para que esta imprima otra cosa sin que al aplicarle los paréntesis esta se ejecute. Algo similar a esto:

```
repeat(3, console.log("Hola amigos como les va?"));
```

Mi idea era repetir cualquier tipo de acciones por ejemplo:

```
repeat(10, dibujarCuadrados(width, height, color));
repeat(5, enviarNotificacion(mensaje));
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Que tal si lees algo [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function), si no resuelvee eso tu pregunta intenta modificarla y explicarte un poco mejor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puede hacerlo agregando un callback:

ejemplo:

```js
function hacer_algo(s){
  console.log(s);
}

function repeat(n, action) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        action();
    }
}
// antiguo
repeat(3, function () { console.log("bien y usted?")});

// moderno
repeat(3, () => hacer_algo("hola como estas?"));
```